# Need to change DSRM password on multiple W2K3 DC's (Automatically) without entering password manually

Tags: shell, vbscript, windows-server-2003

```
ntdsutil "set dsrm password" "reset password on server %1" "newpassword" "newpassword" q q
```

I have tried but still it is asking password manually please provide me some script to enter password automatically when it prompts.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"):
  WshShell.Run "cmd", 9:
  WScript.Sleep 500:
  WshShell.SendKeys " ntdsutil ":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{set dsrm password}":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{sync from domain account Admin}":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}":
  WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World!":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}":
  WScript.Sleep(2000):
  WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World!":
  WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}":
```